# Javascript - Looping through spreadsheet merged cells

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, merge

I am looping through a range of data in a Google Spreadsheet in Google Apps Script.

The problem I'm having is I have some merged cells that have the same value, for example C:6 to E:6 all have the same value as those 3 cells are merged.

So, in my loop it will show `C:6 = 'Focus and targeting'` `D:6 = ''` and `E:6 = ''` What I'm trying to do is in my loop assign the 2nd and 3rd values to the first cell value.

Here is what I have:

```
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Audit');
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = range.getNumRows();
  var numCols = sheet.getMaxColumns();
  var values = range.getValues();
  
  var count = 0;
  for (var i = 2; i <= numCols - 2; i++) {
   
    var questionCategory = values[5][i];
   
       
    if(questionCategory == undefined) {
      continue;
    }
   
    if(questionCategory == "") {
       // need to assign 2nd and 3rd cells of merged list to have the value of 1st cell in merged list     
    }
    
    count++;
    
  }
```

Here is what the data looks like:

[image]

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Comment: You can check if cells are merged with isPartOfMerge https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#ispartofmerge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is custom function to get merged cell value:

```
function getMergedCellValue(cellRange)
{
  if (!cellRange.isPartOfMerge())
  {
    return cellRange.getDisplayValue();
  }

  return cellRange.getMergedRanges()[0].getDisplayValue();
}
```

And updated code using this function:

```
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Audit');
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = range.getNumRows();
  var numCols = range.getNumColumns();
  var values = range.getValues();

  var count = 0;
  var questionRowNum = 6;
  for (var i = 0; i < numCols; i++)
  {
    // assign 2nd and 3rd cells of merged list to have the value of 1st cell in merged list  
    var questionCategory = values[questionRowNum-1][i] || getMergedCellValue(sheet.getRange(questionRowNum, i+1));

    count++;
  }
```